# TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my data which called car_A :

```
    Source
0   CAULAINCOURT
1   MARCHE DE L'EUROPE
2   AU MAIRE
```

I would like to find from all path from sources to destination something like:

```
    Source                    Destination
0 CAULAINCOURT           MARCHE  DE L'EUROPE
2 CAULAINCOURT                AU MAIRE
3 MARCHE DE L'EUROPE        AU MAIRE
.
.
.
```

I already have tried

```
for i in car_A['Names']:
  for j in range(len(car_A)-1):
    car_A = car_A.append(car_A.iloc[j+1,0])
```

But i got

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

How can i get mentioned dataset?

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit? What is `car_A['Names']`? What do you mean by "path from sources to destination"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to build a set of all of the pairs, filter to remove when the source and destination are the same location, and then construct a new data frame.

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame({'sources': [
    "CAULAINCOURT",
    "MARCHE DE L'EUROPE",
    "AU MAIRE"
]})

df_pairs = pd.DataFrame(
    filter(lambda x: x[0]!=x[1], product(df.sources, df.sources)), 
    columns=['source', 'dest']
)

df_pairs
# returns:
               source                dest
0        CAULAINCOURT  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE
1        CAULAINCOURT            AU MAIRE
2  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE        CAULAINCOURT
3  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE            AU MAIRE
4            AU MAIRE        CAULAINCOURT
5            AU MAIRE  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE
```

Answer (score 5):

A small variation on the fine answer from @James. `itertools.permutations` removes the duplicates for you.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import permutations

df = pd.DataFrame({'sources': [
    "CAULAINCOURT",
    "MARCHE DE L'EUROPE",
    "AU MAIRE"
]})

df_pairs = pd.DataFrame(
    [x for x in permutations(df.sources, 2)],
    columns=['source', 'dest'])

df_pairs
# returns
               source                dest
0        CAULAINCOURT  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE
1        CAULAINCOURT            AU MAIRE
2  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE        CAULAINCOURT
3  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE            AU MAIRE
4            AU MAIRE        CAULAINCOURT
5            AU MAIRE  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, using [`DataFrame.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Source': [
    "CAULAINCOURT",
    "MARCHE DE L'EUROPE",
    "AU MAIRE"
]})

df = df.assign(key=1).merge(df.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', 1).rename(columns={'Source_x':'Source', 'Source_y':'Destination'})
df = df[df.Source != df.Destination]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               Source         Destination
1        CAULAINCOURT  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE
2        CAULAINCOURT            AU MAIRE
3  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE        CAULAINCOURT
5  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE            AU MAIRE
6            AU MAIRE        CAULAINCOURT
7            AU MAIRE  MARCHE DE L'EUROPE
```